# Set cell value in Pandas DataFrame based on a value in another DataFrame with same index/column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like the following, with a hourly time index, and column names corresponding to a particular location:

```
df1.head()

                        33643  33667  33668  33677  33678  33680  33681  33686
   1998-01-01 10:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
   1998-01-01 11:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
   1998-01-01 12:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
   1998-01-01 13:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
   1998-01-01 14:00:00  322.0  343.0  323.0  341.0  342.0  342.0  341.0  343.0
```

I have a second Pandas DataFrame  with the same index and column names, with a different variable.

```
df2.head()

                        33643   33667   33668   33677   33678   33680   33681
   1998-01-01 10:00:00  289.59  286.07  286.52  284.77  285.17  284.17  284.44   
   1998-01-01 11:00:00  289.83  286.31  286.76  285.00  285.40  284.39  284.66   
   1998-01-01 12:00:00  290.08  286.63  287.08  285.33  285.73  284.73  284.99   
   1998-01-01 13:00:00  290.39  287.27  287.68  286.10  286.46  285.56  285.80   
   1998-01-01 14:00:00  291.10  289.14  289.39  288.42  288.64  288.09  288.23
```

I would like to find where in df1 values equal np.nan, and if so, insert np.nan for the corresponding cell in df2. I have tried looking at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html), but I haven't found them of much use. Other Stackoverflow pages haven't been super helpful. Here is my desired output:

```
df3.head()

                        33643  33667  33668  33677  33678  33680  33681  33686
   1998-01-01 10:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
   1998-01-01 11:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
   1998-01-01 12:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
   1998-01-01 13:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN   
   1998-01-01 14:00:00  291.10  289.14  289.39  288.42  288.64  288.09  288.23 289.12
```

Things I have tried:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df1[:] == np.nan, df2[:] == np.nan, df2[:]))

df3 = df2.where(df1.iloc[:,:] == np.nan, np.nan)
```

Any suggestions? Am I on the right path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you're not far from the solution, in fact, you're thinking right. But if I had to recommend a method I would recommend this using [pandas.notnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html)

```
df3 = df2[pd.notnull(df1)]
```

you just pick cells from `df2` where `df1` is `not null` and put them in the corresponding cells in `df3`, all the others will be set to `NaN` automatically.

If you still wanna use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) you could do something like this with [pandas.isnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html):

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(pd.isnull(df1),np.nan,df2))
```

but then you'll have to use the `columns` parameter to rename the columns. Also this method is a bit slower so I wouldn't really use it personally.

Hope this was helpful.

output ( I only took your first 2 cols in my sample just to go faster ):

```
                     33643   33667
1998-01-01 10:00:00    NaN     NaN
1998-01-01 11:00:00    NaN     NaN
1998-01-01 12:00:00    NaN     NaN
1998-01-01 13:00:00    NaN     NaN
1998-01-01 14:00:00  291.1  289.14
```

Comment: Awesome, pd.notnull() worked great. I tend to overthink these things and try to come up with some incredibly complex slicing technique. Thanks!